# Comparing index of array of structs to NULL not evaluating to true;

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, struct, null

I have an array of Structs and I am passing that to a function. I then check an index of that array to see if it is NULL, which it should be at this point. The thing is that comparing it to NULL does not evaluate to true.

This is where I declare the struct and create the array.

```
typedef struct ListStruct {
    NodePtr first;
    NodePtr last;
    NodePtr current;
    int numNodes;
} ListStruct;

typedef struct ListStruct* ListHndl

ListHndl* newHash(int size){
    ListHndl* arr = malloc ( size*sizeof( ListHndl ));
    for(int y = 0; y<size; y++){
        arr[y] = NULL;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Then I pass it to a function like this

```
function(ListHndl* HashTable)
```

and compare an index to null

```
if(HashTable[index] == NULL) {
    //stuff that doesn't happen but should
}
```

This shows some of the function which uses the array.

```
void insert(int ID, char* title, int size, ListHndl* HashTable){
    int index = hash(title, size);
    if(HashTable == NULL ){
        printf("can't insert hash table is null");
        return;
    }
    //If the 'bucket' at the hashed index is empty, create a new list and initialize it appropriately
    if(HashTable[index] == NULL){
        //Do stuff, this doesn't get called even though it should
    }else{
        //do other stuff, this shouldn't be done when the function is called the first time but does in this case  
    }
```

This is the test program. It crashes on the first insert.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "list.h"
#include "hash.h"

int main(){

    ListHndl temp = newHash(5);
    printf("new hash created!\n");
    insert(1, "munches", 5, temp);
    printf("insertion has occurred! :)\n");
    insert(2, "aids", 5, temp);
    insert(3, "loki", 5, temp);
    insert(4, "kelp", 5, temp);
    insert(5, "kelp", 5, temp);
    printf("insertion has occured!\n");
    lookup(&temp, "munches", 5);
    lookup(&temp, "aids", 5);
    lookup(&temp, "loki", 5);
    lookup(&temp, "kelp", 5);
    printf("WE LIVE!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the hash function used to get an index for the Hash table.

```
int hash (const char* word, int size)
{
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; word[i] != '\0' ; i++)
    {
        hash = 31*hash + word[i];
    }
    return hash % size;
}
```

Comment: How big is `size` and `index` ? Are you using an `index` which is greater than or equal to `size`?

Comment: In the test we did, size is 5 and the hashing function returns a number which was modulo the size so it should be less than size.

Comment: OK. Can you post a small self-contained complete program which demonstrates the problem? There might be an issue in the code that we can't see!

Comment: Edited post to show more code

Comment: Can you maybe post the code that calls `newHash` then invokes `function`?

Comment: Does the code compile without warnings? As it stands it doesn't, as at least the necessary `#include` statements are missing.

Comment: Edited. The code compiles and runs but seg faults during the first insert call

Comment: Are you sure it's not the `hash` function that's failing?

Comment: I posted the hash function. I think it works fine though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains a number of obvious errors, which are most likely causing your issues. Function `newHash` is declared as returning `ListHndl*` value

```
ListHndl* newHash(int size)
```

Yet in `main` you use it as if it returns a `ListHndl` value

```
ListHndl temp = newHash(5);
```

This does not make any sense and will certainly produce diagnostic messages from the compiler (something about pointer type mismatch). You apparently ignored these diagnostic messages and ran the program anyway.

Later in the code you again pass that `temp` value (of type `ListHndl`) to functions that probably expect `ListHndl *` arguments. This also surely generated diagnostic messages from the compiler, and you ignored them too.

Don't ignore diagnostic messages. Fix the problems (errors and warnings) you have in your code. Proceed from there. What you have now is rather meaningless specifically because of such errors.

Comment: The thing is that it compiles fine like this and changing it to ListHndl* gave us errors. Maybe that fixed it and uncovered more errors? I didn't look at the errors.

Comment: @Raulito28: The only reason it can "compile fine" is if you are calling functions without declaring them first (classic C allows that). Without seeing the function declarations the compiler cannot catch type mismatches, as the one I described above. Firstly, declare functions with prototypes before calling them. Secondly, get rid of type mismatches. I don't know how you could possibly get errors after changing to `ListHndl *`. Maybe your code has more issues that we can't see in what you posted so far.

Comment: OK, I changed `ListHndl` to `ListHndl*`, I was getting errors because I was passing the address of the ListHndl to the function, but now I have the same problem I had before. It does HashTable[index] == NULL but that doesn't evaluate to true even though in `newHash()` mallocs the appropriate amount of memory and then loops through it to make it NULL. I don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: @Raulito28: Well, there's no way to say what it could be without seeing the actual code you are working with.

Comment: Turns out that the comparison to NULL wasn't causing a problem, there was another problem causing a seg fault so it wasn't calling the print statements I used to test the if statement and made it look like it didn't take the if branch. Now, I have the problem that I set the `void * data` field of a linked list to the address of an int and the int at that address gets overwritten when I pass the LinkedList to a function. It gets overwritten with another int that is also being passed into the function. Any ideas? Thanks for your help so far!